# CSS - Action de overlay

Tags: html, css, css-hover, helper

Amigos sou não entendo muito de CSS ou HTML, mas consigo me virar com algumas coisas. Estou criando meu site (https://girundi.com/) só que esto precisando de um help:

Como criei no cargocollective o template é pronto, então modifiquei algumas coisas. Só que queria colocar em cada imagem a função de overlay - ou seja, quando passar o mouse sob ela, aparece o nome do projeto e ela fica mais escura. A ideia é igualzinho a desse site aqui (http://www.brunooppido.com/).

Alguem sabe como faço?

Comment: Vi onde queres chegar, mas podes postar pelo menos algum codigo funcional (parte do HTML, CSS e JS se necessario) assim a gente pode dar o nosso parecer?

Comment: Leia sobre o efeito [*hover*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) do CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue um modelo bem simples. Preferi fazer dessa forma mais simples com os elementos separados apenas para vc entender melhor como funciona o efeito. Mas também é possível fazer usando *pseudo elements*, *attrs* etc.

De uma olhada no modelo abaixo que acho que vai te atender. (não deixe de estudar o código)

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #000;
}
.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.container:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.text a, a:visited, a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placecage.com/200/200" alt=" " class="image">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="text"><a href="#">Nome do Projeto</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1

Ola meu caro!
Primeiramente obrigado pela ajuda. Com não tenho frequencia nesse site, demorei para visualizar. Entrei em contato com um programador que conheço e ele fez o freela para mim. Dê uma olhada la depois!

Bom, eu dei uma estuda e conversando com ele vi que a plataforma que hospedei o site não tem uma versão em HTML como eu pensava o que facilitaria eu criar o cógido. Dessa maneira se eu apenas adicionasse o overly como código HTML não iria nunca funcionar. Para tal foi necessário copiar o código da página e escrever ele todo de novo para ter saida em HTML e facilitar o job

Comment: @WilliamGirundi legal que deu certo! Cada framework funciona de um jeito, as vezes complica mesmo. Mas tente não ficar na mão de programador, estude bastante e aprenda a fazer por conta própria. Sucesso!